# Remembered values, and scope gone from memory, in a Python Closure

Tags: python, closures

Below is a simple piece of code I found in [this](https://stephensugden.com/crash_into_python/FunctionalProgramming.html) tutorial.

Here's a nice definition of Closure I found [here](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/python-closures-explained.html): *"a function object that remembers values in enclosing scopes regardless of whether those scopes are still present in memory."*

I gather that `rotate()` below is a closure. Please help me understand what values is it remembering even after their scope is gone from memory (and why does their scope leave memory)?

```
def make_rotater(seq):
    def rotate():
        val = seq.pop(0)
        seq.append(val)
        return val
    return rotate

r = make_rotater([1,2,3])
r()
# 1
r()
# 2
```

---

(Update) Part 2: Why does the (closure-less) code below not work?

```
def make_rotater(seq):
    val = seq.pop(0)
    seq.append(val)
    return val

r = make_rotater([1,2,3])
r()
# File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It remembers local values from make_rotator so if u do:

```
def make_rotater():
    seq=[1,2,3]
    def rotate():
        val = seq.pop(0)
        seq.append(val)
        return val
    return rotate
```

The seq is referenced by rotate, so it will remain in memory for when you will call rotate, even though it was defined in make_rotater (that is already done, and cleaned from memory)

When you call make_rotater it creates a new seq and defines the rotate method that references seq, so one you leave make_rotater it's memory isn't needed except seq, (cause rotate still uses it). When you will no longer reference rotate, seq will also be cleaned

part 2:

your method now doesnt return another method it returns the number directly, so you dont need to do r()

you can use it like this:

```
seq = [1,2,3]
def make_rotater(seq):
    val = seq.pop(0)
    seq.append(val)
    return val

r = make_rotater(seq)

print r # prints 1, note there is no r() just r
r = make_rotater(seq)
print r # prints 2
r = make_rotater(seq)
print r # prints 3
```

Comment: There's no need to change the example from the question; function parameters are local variables, too.

Comment: Also, nothing has been cleaned from memory; the list referenced by `seq` is the same value, though the local name `seq` in `make_rotater` is no longer in scope.

Comment: Yea but it makes it clearer(since he could be referencing seq from outside of make_rotater too, and that will also cause seq to remain in memory )

Comment: I agree that changing the example from the question helped make it clearer for me.

Comment: @chepner re: "the list referenced by `seq` is the same value", you mean that it's still `[1,2,3]` ? But that ***that*** `seq` is no longer in scope, and that the `seq` that's in scope (due to the closure) may have a different value? Is this what you meant?

Comment: Scope refers to names, not values. The list object referenced by the name `seq` in `make_rotater` is the exact same object referenced by the name `seq` inside `rotate`. The difference between a closure and a normal function is that the closure has a separate namespace attached to it containing names inherited from the environment it was defined in that is used before its global namespace.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. That makes sense. I updated my original question with a Part 2 (similar code without the closure)... if you have time and the inclination, I'd highly appreciate an answer on why that didn't work.

Comment: @DorElias Thank you very much for updating the answer with part 2. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That definition is sort of right, sort of wrong. It depends on what you mean by a scope being "still present in memory". I'd say a better definition would be "a function object that remembers *variables* in enclosing scopes regardless of whether those scopes are still present *on the call stack*."

When you call `make_rotater`:

```
def make_rotater(seq):
    def rotate():
        val = seq.pop(0)
        seq.append(val)
        return val
    return rotate
```

The `rotate` closure keeps the `seq` variable alive even after execution leaves the scope of `make_rotater`. Ordinarily, when execution leaves a function, its local variables would cease to exist.